# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

its my first project with symfony and i tried to make a login page. i found a Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xhYwwznIWU) everything work like in the video but then i try to use "php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load" the error :

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM user':
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user

comes. 
i dont really know that i did wrong because i did everything like in the video

thx for help

Comment: Did you resolve you problem?

Comment: not really, now it says access denied for 'root'@'localhost' and i dont know how to fix it..... but thx for you comment. how i close my question? i am new here

Comment: are you forget password to database?

Comment: when and where i need to write my password?

Comment: In `app/config/parameters.yml` database_password: yourPass

Comment: thx dude that help

Comment: Tesekurler olsun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to run command update schema:

a. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` // show your status database if have some changes shows

b. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

2) If you use Symfony2 run command with `php app/console ...`

3) Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' ... error is you have not access to you Database(Mysql, PostgreSql, MongoDB...). Your password or username is not valid.

Your **track trace error** is saying user table is not exists.

And I suggest you to read always read error message (track trace) like that.

***Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException***

**'DELETE FROM user': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user**